# How i can do a function who can be applied to any variables at the end of the variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a function like .split() or .replace() or .remove(), i think is like a prototype function, how i can make this example works:

```js
this.logThis = function(a) {
  console.log("The " + this + "is cool like a " + a);
}

var food = "apple";
food.logThis("orange");
```

To get this Output:

```
> "The apple is cool like a orange"
```

**Important: I need the most short code possibly, pure javascript, NO JQUERY**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please show us what have you tried and include a [mcve]

Comment: Why can't you make a function with two parameters that prints them into a statement?

Comment: Yes, but my example is showing my bad code, thats why im tryng find a solution...

Comment: Im looking for a structure like this: variable.andFunctionHere()

Comment: I can do a function with two parameters, of course like this: function logThis(variable,a) {}; but i need the structure like .split() or .replace()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will preface this by saying that generally, you don't want to extend prototypes. For that I will refer you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice).

However - if you really wanted to, you could:

```
String.prototype.logThis = function(a) {
  console.log("The " + this + " is cool like a " + a);
}

var food = "apple";
food.logThis("orange");
```

Comment: Can i use a custom replacing of "String." with "Int" or "Object", for apply the function to any type of variable?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Classes: https://javascript.info/class

Comment: Thankyou, i already Works good, i replace with Number.prototype.LogThis(); using a example with intergers and works so nice... i can mix absolutly all with that...

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be able to call the function on a string, you'll need to extend the `String` prototype:

```js
String.prototype.logThis = function(a) {
  console.log("The " + this + " is cool like a " + a);
}

var food = "apple";
food.logThis("orange");
```

This'll work, but you might want to alter it slightly to use a more modern JavaScript syntax:

```js
String.prototype.logThis = function(a) {
  console.log(`The ${this} is cool like a ${a}`);
}

const food = "apple";
food.logThis("orange")
```

It is also worth pointing out that extending native objects is considered by many to be a bad practice ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)), so you might rather alter your function to avoid this.

Here's one way of doing that:

```js
const obj = {
  food: 'apple',
  logThis(a) {
    console.log(`The ${this.food} is cool like a ${a}`);
  }
}

obj.logThis("orange");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your code works fine!, i appreciate your answer...

Comment: No worries. If it helps, I'd be obliged if you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: Can i replace the "String." to "Int." or "Object.", for apply the function to any type of variable?

Comment: Or maybe the String.prototype, automatically can be used for any type of variable, for example: var obj = { "name" : "chicken"}; obj.logThis("hen");

Comment: Sorry, stepped away from the PC for a while, but it looks like you found your answer.

Comment: You both have the answer, how i can decide?

Comment: It's just nice if you accept one of the answers, which you already did, so all good :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer too, you have other methods... <3

Comment: Can you give me a review of my Answer of this post?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903412/using-onclick-on-span-elements/55903648#55903648